# Linux: Copy files with dates in filename between two dates

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I have a folder full of files where I from time to time need to copy a subset of these to somewhere else for processing.

The files have the date they were created in the filename, i.e. filename_20131028.txt.

How do I go about selecting and copying the files between two dates. Optimally I'd like to make a script like 'get_my_foo_files.sh 20131010 20131025' and get the files between 10th october and 25th october.

Thanks in advance.

*Edit*: I'm open for solutions in Python/Perl as well.

Comment: Are all the filenames the same, or do they differ?

Comment: The 'filename'-part above of the fulle filenames are the same, they only differ on the datepart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU `date` you can loop through a range of YYYYMMDD format dates easily:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
first=$1
last=$2

while [[ $first -le $last ]]; do
    match=$(date +%Y%m%d  -d $first)
    echo "filename_${match}.txt"
    first=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "$first 1 day")
done
```

Add your processing instead of `echo ...`.
This uses [date arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#SEC127), where "n day" is addition of days to the given date, "-n day" also works for subtraction (though watch out for [this beartrap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497639/subtract-time-using-date-and-bash) if HH:MM is present too).

(In case you ever encounter it, ancient `date` (*sh-utils* era) versions allowed an `mktime()` normalisation feature, you could simply keep incrementing the day-of-month up to 99, and it would silently fix it for you:

```
 $ date -d 20160832
 Thu Sep  1 00:00:00 IST 2016
```

)

Something very similar (but arguably not identical in behaviour) can also [be done with filesystem timestamps](https://superuser.com/questions/560598/how-list-file-by-range-of-date) using GNU `find` and its modification time related options (`-mtime`, `-daystart` and more).

A possibly useful variation is to use bash's *extended globbing* (via `@(pattern)`) so you can deal with all the files in one go:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
first=$1
last=$2

globlist=$1
while [[ $first -le $last ]]; do
    first=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "$first 1 day")
    globlist="${globlist}|${first}"
done 

shopt -s nullglob extglob
filelist="$(echo filename_@($globlist).txt)"  # NB whitespace in filenames
echo "filelist is: $filelist"

filearr=( filename_@($globlist).txt )  # safer for troublesome names
declare -p filearr
```

This also sets `nullglob` so that zero matches results in an empty string rather than an error.
This is useful when it's better to perform a single operation on multiple files (e.g. `tar` or `rsync`).

Comment: That's brilliant, I didn't know about the date arithmetic! That will come in handy in other situations.